# Select from table where columns names equal data in a different table

Tags: php, mysql

I am running this SQL Query:

```
$sql2="SELECT * from callplanmeta ";
$rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
{
    $column_list[] = $result2["callplanname"];
}

$sql="SELECT LEAST(NULLIF(".implode(',',$column_list).",0)) as num FROM callplandata ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    echo $result["description"].' - '.$result["num"].'<br><br>';
}
```

So in the callplanmeta table are rows with the column names for the callplandata table.

This query is working fine but I need a way to stop it from showing values that are zero from the `$result["num"]` result. I want it to not show the zero values and just show the next one for every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
$sql="SELECT LEAST(NULLIF(".implode(',',$column_list).",0)) as num FROM callplandata WHERE LEAST(NULLIF(".implode(',',$column_list).",0)) != 0";
```

instead of:

```
$sql="SELECT LEAST(NULLIF(".implode(',',$column_list).",0)) as num FROM callplandata ";
```

Comment: i am getting this error Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'NULLIF'

Comment: and if i try $sql="SELECT LEAST(".implode(',',$column_list).") as num FROM callplandata WHERE num IS NOT NULL"; i get the error: Unknown column 'num' in 'where clause'

Comment: If you only want to sort out rows where one column is 0 you can do: $sql="SELECT LEAST(".implode(',',$column_list).") as num FROM callplandata WHERE num IS NOT 0"; (if it still doesn't work send me a message)

Comment: hmmm... now im getting this error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0' at line 1